# Equation for plotting point on opposite side of a sphere using direction

Tags: vectors, spheres

I am creating an infinite object scroller for a 3D game and need to find the opposite point on a sphere using direction.

[image: Plotting points on Circle]

If you look at the image above, I have point A as a Vector3 (x, y, z) and direction C as a Vector (x, y, z) and I need to find the point B.

The sphere has a radius of 500 and lies at an origin of 0,0,0

Can someone please give me the equation or point to a reference somewhere? thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To have a unique answer, you would also need to include information about the sphere. Can you specify that?

Comment: Thanks @Hrodelbert, it is a sphere with a radius of 500, what other info would be needed?

Comment: Next to its radius, its location is important: where does the center lie? At the origin?

Comment: Yes it is a perfect sphere with origin at 0,0,0. I'll update the question to include this

Comment: How about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point ${\bf B}$ is the reflection of the point ${\bf A}$ through the plane through the origin orthogonal to (the nonzero) vector ${\bf C}$, so the point ${\bf B}$ is just the image of $\bf A$ under the [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) corresponding to the unit vector $\frac{\bf C}{|{\bf C}|},$ and so 
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{{\bf B} = {\bf A} - 2 \left(\frac{{\bf A} \cdot {\bf C}}{{\bf C} \cdot {\bf C}}\right){\bf C}}} .$$

If one doesn't know about Householder transformations, there's a quick way to derive this formula just using a little vector geometry: Given a parameterization ${\bf L}(t)$ of the line, we are looking for the points where ${\bf L}(t)$ has distance $R$ from the origin, and we can write this condition as $${\bf L}(t) \cdot {\bf L}(t) = R^2 .$$

Now, we have a point $\bf A$ on the line and a direction vector $\bf C$, so we can parameterize the line by $${\bf L}(t) := {\bf A} + t{\bf C}.$$ 
Substituting this formula in our condition gives
$$R^2 = ({\bf A} + t{\bf C}) \cdot ({\bf A} + t{\bf C}) = {\bf A} \cdot {\bf A} + 2 t {\bf A} \cdot {\bf C} + t^2 {\bf C} \cdot {\bf C} .$$ On the other hand, since $\bf A$ is on the sphere, we have ${\bf A} \cdot {\bf A} = R^2$, and so the above equation simplifies to
$$0 = t (2 {\bf A} \cdot {\bf C} + t {\bf C} \cdot {\bf C}) .$$
The r.h.s. is zero iff $t = 0$ or $(2 {\bf A} \cdot {\bf C} + t {\bf C} \cdot {\bf C}) = 0$. When $t = 0$, we have ${\bf L}(0) = {\bf A}$, which is our starting point, so we're interested in the other case. Rearranging and solving for $t$ gives that the other time at which the line intersects the sphere is
$$t^* := -2 \frac{{\bf A} \cdot {\bf C}}{{\bf C} \cdot {\bf C}} .$$
Substituting gives that the intersection point is
$${\bf B} = {\bf L}(t^*) ={\bf A} - 2 \left(\frac{{\bf A} \cdot {\bf C}}{{\bf C} \cdot {\bf C}}\right){\bf C}$$
as claimed.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.